# Filtering h2o dataset by date, but being column imported as time in R

Tags: r, h2o

I have a .csv that I am importing into h2o which has dates stored as "YYYY-mm-dd" format. When I import this into h2o through R, these columns are read in as time (milliseconds) since 1970 (as explained by the problem listed here - https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3434).

```
> head(data.hex$date_used_dt)
   date_used_dt
1 1489449600000
2 1520380800000
3 1469491200000
4 1465862400000
5 1464912000000
6 1516147200000
```

I need to turn this column into a date format. h2o.as_date() cannot work since this is not a factor or string. Is there a function that converts the time variable from h2o to a date *within h2o*? Something like h2o.as_date(), but that could be used on time variables? I need to keep this dataset in h2o.

Answer (score 1):

All dates within h2o are represented like this. Even if you have a character column of dates ("2018-01-01") and you use h2o.as_date() it will be represented in milliseconds.

What you can do if you want to filter on dates is use the `h2o.day`, `h2o.month` and `h2o.year` functions.

`data.hex[h2o.day(data.hex$date_used_dt) == 5, ]` if you only want every 5th day of every month.

Or any combination of month and year like `data.hex[h2o.year(data.hex$date_used_dt) == 2017 & h2o.month(data.hex$date_used_dt) == 12, ]`  if you just want december 2017.